# Retornar nome de Arquivo em Batch

Tags: windows, batch, cmd, prompt

É possível retornar o nome de um arquivo/programa por um bat? Tipo ao arrasta ele para o bat ou executado pelo bat, ele retorna o nome.

Comment: Quando você arrasta um arquivo pro cmd, ele já aparece o nome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, este é um exemplo simples, ele pega o parâmetro "set arg1=%1" e depois mostra o valor "echo %arg1%".

ou

Ele pega o caminho do arquivo que você arrastou "set arg1=%1" e depois mostra o caminho "echo %arg1%".

```
echo off
set arg1=%1
echo %arg1%
pause
```

Vamos supor que você arraste um txt, e queira abrir no notepad por exemplo:

```
echo off
set arg1=%1
start notepad %arg1%
```

Comment: E como usaria isso? Poderia explicar? Fiquei curioso pra testar.

Comment: Você pode pegar este código e colocar em um arquivo batch para ver como funciona, assim que você arrastar pra ele, vai aparecer o caminho na tela.

Comment: Funciona assim, %1 é o primeiro parametro, ai eu coloquei ele na variável arg1 e depois mostrei a variável usando o echo.

Comment: Quer dizer, salvar esse código num .Bat e arrastar qualquer coisa em cima desse executável?

Comment: Exatamente, é assim que funciona.

Comment: Coloquei mais um exemplo para você entender melhor como funciona.

Comment: Conhecia a passagem de parâmetros por batch, mas não sabia que funcionava assim. +1

Comment: Valeu! era exatamente isso que precisava